# Delete objects and arrays with jq which match a key

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have a JSON with the following content:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Test",
      "program": {
        "publicAccess": "--------",
        "externalAccess": false,
        "userGroupAccesses": [
          {
            "access": "r-------"
          },
          {
            "access": "rw------"
          }
        ],
        "id": "MmBqeMLIC2r"
      },
      "publicAccess": "rw------"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want to delete all keys (recursively) which match `publicAccess` or `userGroupAccesses`, so that my JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Test",
      "program": {
        "externalAccess": false,
        "id": "MmBqeMLIC2r"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I've copied `jq`'s builtin `walk` function from [source](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L284).

```
# Apply f to composite entities recursively, and to atoms
def walk(f):
  . as $in
  | if type == "object" then
      reduce keys[] as $key
        ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk(f)) } ) | f
  elif type == "array" then map( walk(f) ) | f
  else f
  end;

# My Code
walk(if (type == "object" and .publicAccess)
        then del(.publicAccess)
     elif (type == "array" and .userGroupAccesses)
        then del(.userGroupAccesses)
     else
       .
end )
```

Gives me `jq: error (at <stdin>:2622): Cannot index array with string "userGroupAccesses"`. Also if I use `.userGroupAccesses[]` - How do I get the result?

Snippet on jqplay: https://jqplay.org/s/1m7wAeHMTu

Comment: You copied from an old builtin.jq. It would be wise to use `keys_unsorted` instead of `keys`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your problem is when `type == "array"` is true `.` will be an array so `.userGroupAccesses` won't work.  What you want to do is focus on the case when `.` is an object.  In your call to `walk` you only need to check for `type == "object"` and then remove the members you don't want.  e.g.

```
walk(if type == "object" then del(.publicAccess, .userGroupAccesses) else . end)
```

[Try it online at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/qpx5knqiPt)

You can also solve this without `walk` by using [Recursive Descent `..`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RecursiveDescent:..)  e.g.

```
del(.. | .publicAccess?, .userGroupAccesses?)
```

[Try it online at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/5BJsU3pyPM)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the recursive descent `..`. I wasn't aware of that and it just made my day.

Comment: If you just need to remove a key from the top level object in an array `jq '.[] | del(.THE_KEY)'`