# Using jq, remove keys that match a regular expression

Tags: json, regex, key, jq

I'd like to remove any fields that match a regular expression, while preserving all other fields and the structure of the JSON.
For example, suppose the JSON looks like this.

```
{
  "this": {
    "foobar": {
      "that": "too"
    },
    "baz": 3,
    "foo": 1
    "morefoo": {
      "foosball": "hi"
    }
  }
}
```

Then the desired output would be

```
{
  "this": {
    "baz": 3,
    "morefoo": {}
  }
}
```

It's possible to do this cleanly by explicitly naming the fields as discussed here:

[Delete objects and arrays with jq which match a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47371280/delete-objects-and-arrays-with-jq-which-match-a-key)

```
jq 'del(.. | .foo?, .foobar?, .foosball?)'
```

but I would like to do this with a regular expression, something like

```
jq 'del(.. | .("^foo")?)'  # This does not work
```

Suggestions?  If possible, I'd rather avoid `with_entries`, but if that's the only way, then so be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using `walk`:

```
walk(if type=="object"
     then with_entries(select(.key | test("^foo") | not))
     else . end)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with recursive descent?

Comment: If you wanted to make the rec. desc. explicit, you could write:   `def d: 
    if type=="object" 
    then with_entries( select(.key | test("^foo") | not) | (.value|=d)) 
    elif type == "array" then map(d) 
    else . end;
  d`